# Column defined by expression being used again in the same Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have used an expression to define open_bal in select statement and
that is used in the case expression below in same select.
This works fine in Sybase anywhere but doesn't work in SQL Server.

```
    SELECT account.acno,   
        account.name,   
        sum( isnull(withdrawl,0) - isnull(deposit,0)) as open_bal,   
        (case when open_bal = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as open_flag
    from account  where....
```

I have used open_bal as a dynamic column in select statement and that is used in the case statement below in same select.
This works fine in Sybase anywhere, but doesn't work in SQL Server.

One solution for this is to have the Sum (isnull(.... function called twice in the both places (shown below), which would increase the time of execution, which is not an ideal solution

```
SELECT account.acno,   
    account.name,   
    sum( isnull(withdrawl,0) - isnull(deposit,0)) as open_bal,   
    (case when sum( isnull(withdrawl,0) - isnull(deposit,0)) = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as open_flag
from account  where....
```

Comment: *"which would increase the time of execution"* why do you think it would? Sybase, under the hood, is going to see `open_bal` as the expression `(case when open_bal = 0 then 0 else 1 end)` as well. If, however, you don't want to repeat the expression use a CTE or derived table (using a `SELECT` or `VALUES` table expression) to define the expression and then you can reference it by its alias.

Answer (score 1):

Using Thom's suggestion, something like these?

```
--CTE 
WITH cte_Open_bal
AS (
    SELECT account.acno,   
        account.name,   
        sum( isnull(withdrawl,0) - isnull(deposit,0)) as open_bal  
    FROM account  
    WHERE....
    )
SELECT c.acno
    ,c.name
    ,c.open_bal
    ,(CASE WHEN c.open_bal = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS open_flag
FROM cte_Open_bal c;

--Subquery
SELECT c.acno
    ,c.name
    ,c.open_bal
    ,(CASE WHEN c.open_bal = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS open_flag
FROM (
    SELECT account.acno,   
        account.name,   
        sum( isnull(withdrawl,0) - isnull(deposit,0)) as open_bal  
    FROM account  
    WHERE....
    ) c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions/understandings:

- Sybase has 4x RDBMS products (ASE, IQ, SQLAnywhere, Advantage) with each having its own SQL dialect; ASE's dialect is rather old and does not support 'newer' features like window functions, CTEs or cross (apply) joins
- I'm going to assume OP is running Sybase ASE (the Sybase RDBMS with the most limited SQL dialect)
- OP has mentioned Sybase and SQL Server so I'm going to assume OP is trying to find a solution that will work in both

One idea using a derived table:

```
select dt.acno,
       dt.name,
       dt.open_bal,
       case when dt.open_bal = 0 then 0 else 1 end as open_flag
from   (SELECT ac.acno,   
               ac.name,   
               sum( isnull(ac.withdrawl,0) - isnull(ac.deposit,0) ) as open_bal  
        from   account ac
        group by ac.acno, ac.name) dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is `CROSS APPLY` which allows you to stack and/or reuse derived values.

Just for fun, I tossed in the `abs(sign(sum(B.openbal)))` ... clearly you could use the `case` if you'd rather.

**Example**

```
SELECT account.acno
      ,account.name
      ,open_bal  = sum( B.openbal )
      ,open_flag = abs(sign(sum(B.openbal)))
from account  
Cross Apply ( values ( isnull(withdrawl,0) - isnull(deposit,0) ) ) B(openbal) 
where....
Group By account.acno,account.name
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and responses. Using derived table will be a good solution, but Iam also trying to check if Cross Apply suggestion will be of any help